# Custom transform not getting applied in wrangler in Google Cloud Data Fusion

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, etl, google-cloud-data-fusion, cdap

I am trying to following custom transform in a wrangler in Google Cloud Data Fusion.

```
set-column column (parse-as-json :column 2 ) ? column =^ "[" : (parse-as-json :column 1 )
```

I want to parse column as JSON to a depth of 2 if it is an array, which means if it starts with a square bracket ([), otherwise to a depth of 1. I am not sure if the colon in `parse-as-json` directive is causing issue here.

If I change it to following, it works fine:-

```
set-column column 'a' ? column =^ "[" : 'b'
```

I have also tried escaping the colon in `parse-as-json` directive with a backslash,still didn't work. What am I doing wrong here? Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

We don't currently support nested directives (ie. set-column with parse-as-json).

You can try first doing a copy of the column, then parse one copy with depth 1, and the parse the clone with depth 2. Then finally you can use the set-column to pick the column that is correct.

For example, if let's say the original column is called 'body', and depth 2 will produce null when it doesn't start with "[", you can do something like this:

```
copy body body_clone
parse-as-json body 1
parse-as-json body_clone 2
set-column final_result !body_clone_field ? body_field : body_clone_field
```